# IE problem with facebook iframe application

Tags: internet-explorer, facebook, iframe

I have a strange problem with my application on facebook on IE (on FF, Opera, Chrome it works fine). Application is using iframe, and when it's trying to load, IE tries to download the content of iframe instead of displaying it...

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: This typically means that the HTTP headers on the content are not correct (e.g. did you send an XHTML MIME type by mistake)?

Comment: @EricLaw-MSFT: you mean MIME type from where? I am using 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html  xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
and having same problem

Comment: can you link app and the full url to your canvas? vliq, hafiz

Answer (score 1):

FF and Chrome will display the file contents in the frame. IE will only display the file contents if the extension is .htm or .txt (and perhaps others), but otherwise, IE will treat it as a download link.